# Can the length of a wire impact SPI transmission?

Tags: led, spi, soldering, wiring

I'm trying to wire a [DotStar LED strip](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2436) to another one. I have soldered on both ends of the added strip:

- VCC to VCC
- GND to GND
- CO to CI
- DO to DI

I'm using SPI to control the LEDs. For some reason, the added strip does not work. **When I test for continuity from the end of the original strip to the beginning of the added strip, I have a closed circuit on VCC and GND, but not on CO to CI not on DO to DI.**

I have soldered, resoldered, cut the strip shorter in case the copper paddings were damaged, but I still don't get any continuity.

Having assembled many of those strips together with success, I don't understand what's going on this time. The only difference I noted is that the wires I used to connect those strips are longer than I usually do (about 8 inches long).

So my question is: *Can the length of the wires impact the good functioning of SPI?*

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Here's the (unorthodox) wiring schematics, hope this clarifies the question.
[image: Wiring schematics]

Comment: You should have continuity across the part you wired. You won't have any continuity on CO/CI/DO/DI at different points on the strip - that's normal - but where you connected two strips you should certainly have continuity there, that's what the wires you added are *for*!

Comment: Are you using different color wires?  It sounds like they got reversed (CO to DI and vice versa).

Comment: @user253751 could you please explain why it is normal that I won't have continuity on different points of the strip for CO/CI and DO/DI? I've added a schematics, maybe that will help.

Comment: From the picture provided it looks like you do not have continuity between two ends of the same wire. Is that what you _really_ mean? Because then you can get only one advice - find better wire.

Comment: @Maple yes that's what I mean, I get an open circuit signal between DO/DI and CO/CI, I might as well just go with another approach for this system if I can't make it work.

Comment: @garys DI for the first LED isn't connected to DI for the second LED. DO for the first LED is connected to DI for the second LED. But all the VCCs and GNDs are connected together for all the LEDs.

Comment: @user253751 noted. I thought they were connected but that makes more sense otherwise how could I address the LEDs individually, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the length of the wires used for SPI can affect the functionality. Longer wires give more capacitance, which is harder to switch high and low at high data rates. But longer wires will still conduct current, and a continuity test is at low frequency, so something else is going on herre.

Try measuring the actual resistance of the connecting wires instead of using a continuity checker. It would also be helpful if you drew a schematic of how you are connecting the strips and exactly where you are measuring continuity. Also, the link you provided is the top-level link to the vendor, not to that specific product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought too, but I still can't figure out why the continuity wouldn't positive for CO/CI and DO/DI. I've done the soldering over and over with different ends and LEDs, it just won't work. I've added the schematics, hope this helps. I'm going to check the resistance as well as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Wiring length can have a negative impact on SPI communication, which is best for communication between devices on the same PCB (short runs of copper). However, I do not think this is the cause of your problem. It sounds like you may have a defective strip, or defective cable, since you aren't getting continuity on your communication lines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in particular, the clock signal of SPI is a problem at longer lengths. Think about it:

The master clocks data sent to the slave and those bits travel alongside each other down the cable so that is fine. But the master also clocks data sent by the slave which means that the slave can only send its bit when it receives the clock pulse. That the wires have to be short enough so that bits sent by the slave are able to get back to the master before the master sends the next clock pulse, or else the master will associate the received bit from the slave with the wrong clock cycle.

But this should not be an issue at your lengths.